# In git how can I commit to master without merging?

Tags: git, squash

TL;DR; I want a way to tell git "master has a new revision that looks exactly the same as the tip of feature A, but without the history".

Is there a way to do this?

[Update: I now have a workflow that minimizes this problem, but I would still like to know how to tell git to do the following:-

Commit a single change to a branchX, to make all files and folders match those at the tip of branch Y. Is that possible?]

---

*The Back Story*

We usually avoid branching from feature branches.. but had to in this case. Here is what we tried to do :-

```
master   o-----------------o---------------o       
          \               /[squash]       /
feature A  o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o               / [squash] -- too many conflicts
                  \                     /
feature B          o-o-o-o-------------o
```

For various reasons we always squish onto master. But as feature B had a bunch of changes in common with feature A, the second squish had lots of merge conflicts.

I tried this...

```
master   o-----------------o----------------o       
          \               /[squash]        / [squash]  -- same set of conflicts!!
feature A  o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o----------------o
                  \                      / (merge) -- easy
feature B          o-o-o-o--------------o
```

The (merge) was easy, and left feature A with exactly the set of files I want master to have (as feature A and master had the same files after it was merged to master). This merge was easy as Git knew that only conflicts after feature B branched needed resolving.

At that point I then want to commit the now merged feature A branch to master. BUT I get the same set of conflicts I was trying to avoid.

Feature A has all the changes I want... so I could check out master AND feature A and copy all the files into master, then commit. In fact that's what I ended up doing... but surely there is a way to do this with git?!?

I tried generating a binary patch from *master* to *feature A* and then applying it.

```
 git diff --binary master featureA > patch
 git apply patch
```

This failed with "patch does not apply" errors.

I tried various other attempt to merge... all resulting in me having to resolve all the same merge conflicts I already resolved all over again.

---

The reason the merge is a pain from feature B to master is that files changed in feature A before feature B branched are further changed by feature A before commit. This means Git sees these files as changed in feature B, but they differ from those committed in feature A, so a merge is required.

Rebasing feature B on master before committing would mean you again have to perform this merging of file you haven't touched.

Comment: So `master` was untouched from the moment when `feature A` was branched from it?

Comment: There are definitely various ways to resolve this issue with Git, but one of the most straight-forward ways would have just been to rebase branch B onto master before trying to merge. Have you considered doing that? Do you have any reason not to?

Comment: "*The (merge) was easy, and left feature A with exactly the set of files I want master to have (as feature A and master had the same files after it was merged to master).*" That makes very little sense. If branch A and master have no file differences between them, why is it that merging B to A gives you no conflicts, but merging B to master does?

Comment: When you say "squish", you really mean "squash" right (it's official Git terminology, while "squish" is not). "*For various reasons we always squish onto master.*" How? What command(s) do you use to squash our branches onto the master branch?

Comment: Using squashing this way looses you much information. Things like `git blame` and `git bisect` don't work as nice as they could. You'll just see big commits that add everything without the details from each commit why something was done.

Answer (score 2):

There is more than one way to resolve your issue with Git, but **one of the most common methods would just be to simply rebase branch B onto the master branch, before attempting to merge it.**

Assume X is the shared common ancestor commit between branches A and B. Then

1. Rebase B onto master

   ```
   git rebase --onto master X B
   ```

   That will take all commits after X and leading up to B, and re-apply them on top of the master branch. You'll probably need to resolve conflicts still, but you'll resolve them in smaller chunks because you re-apply the commits one by one.
2. Next, you can squash branch B using a soft reset, followed by a commit (note that this is not the only way to squash B):

   ```bash
   git reset --soft X
   git commit -m "Squashing B"
   ```

   Note that you can reverse steps #1 and #2. The only difference is that by squashing B first, you'll end up having to resolve all conflicts at once again after the rebase.
3. Merge B into master,

   ```
   git checkout master
   git merge B
   ```

Alternatively to steps #2 and #3 above, if you did step #1, then you can use `git merge --squash` to squash and merge branch B,

```bash
git checkout master
git merge --squash B
git commit -m "Squashed and merged B"
```

Comment: "That will take all commits after X and leading up to B" --- what if it's not rebaseable?

Comment: @zerkms what do you mean?

Comment: I mean - "commits after X and leading up to B" may be not compatible with `master` to be able to "re-apply them on top of the master ". A trivial example: there is a change for a file that doesn't exist in `master` yet.

Comment: @zerkms the original poster has already stated that B is based off of A, and A has been merged into master. Therefore, with your example, there will be no problem, the changes will apply successfully. Rebasing a branch is equivalent to merging it, and if you run into conflicts, then you just resolve them, the same way you would if you had done a merge.

Comment: "and A has been merged into master" --- actually I'm missing something, but OP states that they cannot merge it because of millions of conflicts. "Rebasing a branch is equivalent to merging it, and if you run into conflicts, then you just resolve them, the same way you would if you had done a merge." --- I know that.

Comment: Oooops, I see now: for some reason I didn't spot the `A -> master` merge in the middle of the Graph.

Comment: @zerkms the OP didn't really make his problem clear enough (yet), but from his description, it sounded like the conflicts were a result of him trying to squash and re-merge commits that were already merged, because he was squashing commits along B that were also a part of A. At least, that's my guess.

Comment: Yep, for some reason the middle of the graph was a blind spot for me, there is a merge yep. Sorry, +1 :-)

Comment: @zerkms no problem, we all have those kind of days on occasion `;)`

Answer (score 0):

The original poster states:

> The (merge) was easy, and left feature A with exactly the set of files I want master to have (as feature A and master had the same files after it was merged to master).

Again, as I pointed out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24358436/in-git-how-can-i-commit-to-master-without-merging#comment37664919_24358436), this makes very little sense, and you didn't list the sequence of commands that led to your results.

However, I will answer your question based solely on this question of yours, ignoring all of the other unclear information (emphasis mine):

> **Commit a single change to a branch X, to make all files and folders match those at the tip of branch Y. Is that possible?**

### Merge with the "Ours" Strategy and Squash

You can make branch X match Y by merging X into Y first, but ignoring all changes from X using the `--strategy ours` or `-s ours` options. Then merge Y back into X (fast-forward merge) while using `--squash`:

```bash
git checkout Y
git merge --strategy ours X

# Verify that Y is unchanged
git diff Y^

git checkout X
git merge --squash Y
git commit

# Verify that X matches Y
git diff Y
```

### Documentation

From the [official git-merge(1) Manual Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html#_merge_strategies):

> #### Merge Strategies
>
> ```
> ours
> ```
>
> This resolves any number of heads, but the resulting tree of the merge is always that of the current branch head, effectively ignoring all changes from all other branches. It is meant to be used to supersede old development history of side branches.

Here is the [documentation for `--squash`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html#_options) as well:

> #### Options
>
> ```
> --squash
> ```
>
> Produce the working tree and index state as if a real merge happened (except for the merge information), but do not actually make a commit or move the HEAD, nor record `$GIT_DIR/MERGE_HEAD` to cause the next `git commit` command to create a merge commit. This allows you to create a single commit on top of the current branch whose effect is the same as merging another branch (or more in case of an octopus).